# BIRT: How to find average of derived measure in cross tab in spago BI?

Tags: birt, crosstab, data-cube

I my **BIRT Report** i am using a **data cube** to show some data with the help of **cross tab**.In the cross tab i added a **derived measure** with the help of other measures.

**Question**:
How to calculate the **average of that derived measure** in the cross tab?

Please give the answer of my question. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case i made a derived measures depending on the other measures.

Suppose i have 2 measures names are  **monthlyRent** and **totalRent**. With the help of these two measure i made a derived measure like this:

```
derived measure = (monthlyRent/totalRent)*100
```

Now i want to calculate the grand total for this derived measure.

**Steps:**

1. Right click on cell.
2. then insert.
3. Dynamic Text.
4. Available Column Bindings.
5. cross tab.
6. then selected the both measures monthlyRent and totalRent.

It will be like this:  `(data["monthlyRent"]/data["totalRent"])*100`

Regarding any help you can contact me i will provide the practical example for this.

Thanks